# How to edit text field in NSOutlineView on a double click?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsoutlineview

In my OSX app I have a **view-based** NSOutlineView. Its rows have text fields that I want to be edited on a **double-click**.

For some reason by default text field would go to the edit mode on a **right-click**. So I want to change it as well as be able to catch the event when the edit is finished to be able to get the new value.

Before I had this NSOutlineView **cell-based** and it was all working properly and I was able to catch the new value in:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
```

After I switched to **view-based** outline view text field would go to the edit mode on a **right-click** and the method above is **not** getting called.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the post that explains how to do the double-click business:

[Respond to mouse events in text field in view-based table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101237/respond-to-mouse-events-in-text-field-in-view-based-table-view)

Although, I still need to figure out how to get the new value!

Found the second part of the question here:

[Delegate events for NSTextField in a view-based NSOutlineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679157/delegate-events-for-nstextfield-in-a-view-based-nsoutlineview)